# IBM DataStage : Job activity does not continue in sequence

Tags: datastage, ibm-infosphere

I have 16 job activities in a sequence, I already define the trigger with OK so they're all connected and auto run when the previous job has finished. I already run and recompiled each job activity on their own but when I recompile and re-run the sequence, somehow only the first job activity run and finished as OK but it does not trigger the next job. Here's the log

```
job_spi_februari..JobControl (@Coordinator): Summary of sequence run
19:18:01: Sequence started
19:18:01: jenis_kredit (JOB job_jenis_kredit) started
19:18:16: jenis_kredit (JOB job_jenis_kredit) finished, status=2 [Finished with warnings]
19:18:16: Sequence finished OK
```

I'm very confused why it's like this, it shows that it goes well without any problem or warning but it does not trigger the next job as it should be as if there's something wrong. What happens actually and how to fix this?

In case, you're curious about my job activity, they all look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AB2d.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you connect all job activites with a OK trigger - the Sequence will end once a single activity does not finish with ok (like "Finished with Warnings") because nothing is left to execute.

If you want to go on I suggest to define a custom trigger which fires on RunOK and Runwarn.